# Boost-MPI HelloWorld Compilation Issues

Tags: libstdc++, boost-mpi

EDIT: solved, incorrect boost setup /facepalm

I have been trying to install boost-mpi on an old system/cluster.

After installing boost and using bjam --with-mpi, i tried to compile a hello_world example that came with the boost-mpi setup tutorial.
I supplied the mpi-autoconfig for bjam with mpic++ and when I compile using the following:

```
/../gnu/bin/mpic++ -I/home/user/boost_1_51_0 communicator.cpp -lstdc++ -L/home/user/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
```

I receive the following errors:

```
libboost_serialization.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<unsigned short>(unsigned short&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.9'
```

So I guessed that GLIBCXX3.4.9 must have been found when building with bjam, but after

```
locate libstdc++.so
```

I used

```
"strings /path/to/libstdc++.so | grep LIBCXX"
```

and each one only had 3.4.8 as the latest version of GLIBCXX.

I am rather confused about this problem.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed mean `libboost_serialization.so` was compiled with a newer version of GCC.

Are you sure you don't have another version installed?  Is your `locate` database up to date?  What does `which g++` show?

Does it help if you put `-lstdc++` last in the compilation command?  Since `liboost_serialization.so` depends on `libstdc++.so` you should order them correctly.

Comment: locate is probably not up to date since the version of gcc on this  cluster was released 5 years ago lol. which g++
simply returns /usr/bin/g++, but it returns gcc version 4.1.2
placing -lstdc++ last also did not change the errors unfortunately